AVocent ACS32 console cable
I have a avocent acs32 and and a juniper qfx10002-36q, i want to connect my qfx1k console port to avocent acs32 to be able to manage it as out of band,
should i use normal ethernet cable to connect them or should i use crossover cable?

Console ports are typically serial interfaces, and they need a special cable. You cannot connect the serial interface to an ethernet interface.

While an "ethernet" cable will often work, the twist and pairing can create noise for single ended serial signals. When the entire building is wired with cate5e/6 cables, you use what you have. :-)

Edit: tl;dr - yes, use a regular ethernet cable
I'd like to restate your question to verify what you're asking. I believe you have the following:
Devices:

1 Avocent ACS32 Terminal Server with available serial ports
1 Juniper QFX10002-36q Network Switch with an open console port

Current Access Levels:

You can access and configure the Avocent ACS32 Terminal Server and you are able to configure the serial ports, and
You can access and configure the Juniper QFX10002-36q Network Switch
via the console port with an USB-to-"Cisco Serial (8P8C)" cable or
other port-to-RS232-to-8P8C connector.

Goal:
To use Avocent ACS32 Terminal Server to manage the Juniper QFX10002-36q Network Switch via the switch console port connected to an available Serial Port on the Avocent.
Answer:
Assuming the above is correct, yes, using a regular ethernet cable (non-rollover) is the appropriate way to cable between the two devices. Make sure the configure the serial port you use on the Avocent to "Terminal Server (TS)" mode. In order to connect via SSH through the terminal server to the Juniper QFX, per the Avocent User Guide page 26 you would issue the following command:
ssh -l username:TCP_port_number console_server_IP_address|or the hostname


"use a regular ethernet cable" There is no such thing as a "regular" ethernet cable. Ethernet runs on a variety of media, from coax to fiber, and various grades on each media type. Is it Category-6a UTP, OM3 Multimode Fiber, OS1 Singlemode fiber? What exactly do you think a "regular" ethernet cable is?
